# Kubernetes Federation - Issue when joining cluster MS Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am running a cluster in west-us for federation in MS Azure. I installed coredns and ran kubefed as following:

```
kubefed init productores-fed --host-cluster-context=edge-westus-5a01b24d --dns-provider="coredns" --dns-zone-name="sancristobal.com.ar." --dns-provider-config="./coredns-provider.conf"Creating a namespace federation-system for federation system components... done
Creating federation control plane service................................................... done
Creating federation control plane objects (credentials, persistent volume claim)... done
Creating federation component deployments... done
Updating kubeconfig... done
Waiting for federation control plane to come up............... done
Federation API server is running at: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Then when I tried to join my east-us cluster it failed as belows:

```
kubefed join productores-k8s-cluster-59c2dcaa --host-cluster-context=productores-fed
error: could not find the deployment for controller manager in host cluster
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe we can refer to this [guide](https://github.com/sozercan/k8s-federation-azure-coredns), that guide is a walkthrough for creating Kubernetes cluster federation on Microsoft Azure using CoreDNS.

Comment: Thanks @JasonYe-MSFT , that is the error by following the tutorial actually. I raised a bug into federation per a comment I received on their github.

Comment: Have you enable RBAC for your k8s?

Comment: @HugoMarceloDelNegro did you get this working? Facing the same error on GKE.

Comment: It did not work. I finally implemented my own solution for HA in MS Azure.